# "message":"Missing Authentication Token" every time I used my express get route on AWS API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created this lambda function, and use api gateway to trigger the function. But every time I wanted to use my get route, it keeps returning missing authentication token. I assume, for some reason, the get route isn't listened by lambda or api gateway. Please help, thank you.

```
 //get routes
    app.get("/test1", (req: Request, res: Response)=>{
        console.log(">>>async works",{req, res});
        res.status(200).json({ 
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: "this lambda async get route works" })
        });
    });

    console.log('try 4')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        app.listen(0, ()=>{
            console.log('>>>resolved')
            resolve({
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Server is running" })
            });
        }).on("error", (error)=>{
            console.log('>>>rejected', error)
            reject(error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample output (or more logs) for this code?